# make a list of lists based on variable name

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a list of lists by matching the string `zz`

```
zza=[1,1,1]
zzb=[2,2,2]
zzc=[3,3,3]

final=[]

a= vars()

for i in a:
    if 'zz' in i:
        final.append(a[i])
```

Getting this error `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

desired output: `final = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]`

basically what I'm trying to accomplish is for the code to make me a list automatically based on the variable i set. because I will have many, and don't want to manually append `final` every time I add another list like so:

`final =[zza,zzb,zzc]` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest change that will accomplish your goal is to replace `vars()` with `vars().copy()`. `vars()` changes as you iterate through the for loop. `a = vars()` creates an alias to `vars()`. Since `a` is an alias to `vars()`, `a` will change if `vars()` changes. When the dictionary that you're looping though changes, python throws an exception. The copy of `vars()` that is created with `vars().copy()` does not change as the program executes.

```
zza = [1,1,1]
zzb = [2,2,2]
zzc = [3,3,3]

final = []

a = vars().copy()

for i in a:
    if 'zz' in i:
        final.append(a[i])
```

To demonstrate that `vars()` changes as the program loops through the `for` loop, put `print(vars())` inside the `for` loop and notice that `vars()` is different for every iteration.

For more information about how variable assignment works in python, read https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html. The gist is that `a = b` does not create a copy of `b`. Instead `a` and `b` are names (or aliases) for the same object. One reason that it makes sense for python to use an existing object is that creating a copy of the object uses more memory and processing time.

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: why does it create an alias? i thought i was defining a variable with `a=var()`